# Windows 8.1 keeps asking how to open file types

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a fresh install of Windows 8.1. When I want to open some kind of file (whatever it be, it doesn't matter) some pop-up comes and asks how to open it. I choose a program and it will be opened. Next time I try to open that file type, windows asks how to open it. For example, if I open default programs, I can see that http should be opened via firefox, next time I want to open a http link, windows asks me whether I want to keep opening http links via firefox or I want to change it.

Comment: Try reparing the default file extensios.  http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Is there a checkbox that says something like "always use this program to open this file type"?

Comment: @GeekyDewd No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used `Default Programs` and made programs I want to be default for supported file types, problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as I often open my ebay pages from Turbo Lister and on a new laptop I was constantly being asked (dozens of times per hour). I seem to have solved the problem by going through firefox first and in their tool, options, general tab I set FF to be my default browser.  this then takes you into the defaults on windows and you confirm a couple of things and save your settings. I've just done it and it's working fine at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix it using above methods try this:

1) First method

- go to registry (im my case it didn't work for .jpg files) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg`
- you can find there three keys: OpenWithList, OpenWithProgrids and UserChoice. Please delete the last one, **UserChoice**. After that you should be able to change the default program for that file extension.

2) Second method (if first one doesn't work in your case)

- go to registry `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\`
- find key for 'application name' and delete it. Then do the Open With and set default program to use and it all should works.

Do the same for all types of files which you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can run Microsoft's System File Checker tool. You can do this by going to command prompt and typing 'sfc /scannow' (without quotes). For more info please take a look at [Microsoft's Integrity Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

If a Windows Resource Protection (WRP) file is missing or is corrupted, Windows may not behave as expected. For example, some Windows functions may not work, or Windows may crash. The System File Checker tool (SFC.exe) scans for missing or corrupted system files and repairs them.

EDIT: To open Command Prompt click the start menu > type cmd > right click > and click "Open as administrator"